# Devise - Setting up mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have devise implemented into a rails 3 application. I am trying to get the mailer to work with devise. My current situation is that when I enter an email address which is a default gmail account I have set up. It redirects me back to the 'login' page and gives me a notice 'saying I will recieve instructions soon' however these instructions are not being sent.  I have the same problem as some one who posted on [RubyForum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/215482) I read this post and it didn't help at all. My config/environment/development.rb look like the following:

```
Project::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  #SMTP
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost' }  
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => 'k0903421@gmail.com',
  :password             => '',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

end
```

Is there something I am missing?

When I am redirected back to the login page I get in the console:

```
Sent mail to k0903421@gmail.com (30181ms)
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 14:48:06 +0100
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: k0903421@gmail.com
Message-ID: <4e720216bf59b_3b215d477ae963de@dj.mail>
Subject: Reset password instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello k0903421@gmail.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=fqJXk6JbotIxIv3Awq1s">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/login
Completed 302 Found in 32658ms


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-15 14:48:36 +0100
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  SQL (0.7ms)  describe `roles_users`
  SQL (0.9ms)  describe `roles_users`
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_javascripts.html.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_logo.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered layouts/_errors.html.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (62.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 68.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

**Devise password_controller**

```
def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])

    if successful_and_sane?(resource)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I would change your password asap (never list it online anywhere).  What does the development log show?

Comment: X_x that was accidental. Not to worry its a test email account I set up. Thank you for that

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I receive in the console

Comment: Turn this option to true so that you can see mailer errors in the dev log:   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

Comment: I get the following error: `Timeout::Error in Devise::PasswordsController#create

execution expired`

Comment: It also gives me this `app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:17:in `create'` which means there's something wrong with my create method in the the devise controller

Comment: Yes, something at line 17 is wrong.  Please post that code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3496/discussion-between-james-schorr-and-djj)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
```

Change the email info in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Comment: So should I change `From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com` this to my gmail account?

Comment: Remember to run the server in production mode, otherwise emails will only be shown in the console, not actually sent.

Comment: I previously had this working in development mode. Don't seem to understand why this wouldn't work. I even tried doing a ping to gmail: ping smtp.gmail.com and the connections times out

Comment: I managed to fix my error. I installed mailcatcher https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher and did it this way